# identify if json payload contains non ISO-8859-1 characters

Tags: javascript

I have requirement where my DB should not store any non- ISO-8859-1 charset. There are some legacy systems which might send non-ISO-8859-1 charset to my application and I need to identify these in json payload and reject request based on content. I tried with "decodeURIComponent(escape(payload));" but then it has to be provided with values of each component in JSON one by one. If there is any other way to do this. Please help.

Comment: JSON.stringify the data first, then do a StringToArrayBuffer and check the binary! :D

Comment: Strings in JSON are typically UTF-8 encoded: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8259#section-8.1